# Finding the Pointwise Limit of $f_n$ and testing it's Uniform Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I am fining the pointwise limit of the function $f_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{3-x^n}$ for $x ∈ [0,1]$ and $n ∈ N$

In order to do this I first divided through by $x^n$, yielding me $$ \frac{1}{\frac{3}{x^n}-1}$$

Using this I have determined that $f_n(x) \to f(x) := 
\begin{cases}
0,\ 0 \leq x<1 \\
\frac{1}{2},\ x=1
\end{cases}$

If I assume that I have done this correctly then I could deduce that the convergence cannot be uniform on $[0, 1]$ since each $f_n$ is continuous, but the limit function is not continuous.

Am I correct to make this assumption or is there actually uniform convergence? If there is, how is it determined?

Due to this I have also adjusted the bounds of $x$ to $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ to see if this instead would have uniform convergence.

In this case we would have $f_n(x) \to f(x) := 
\begin{cases}
0,\ 0 \leq x≤\frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}$

What are the implications for the uniform convergence of this? Surely this is also not uniform convergence for similar reasons as above?

I am struggling to get my head around all this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that your analysis of what happens for $x=0$ isn't quite right. Looking at the original sequence, $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Note that the limiting function $f(x)=0$ for $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniform convergence of $(f_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ to $f$ on $[0,1]$ means $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\|f-f_n\|=0$$ where $\|f-f_n\|=\sup\{|f(x)-f_n(x)|: x\in [0,1]\}.$

Each $f_n$ is continuous with $f_n(0)=0$ and with $f_n(1)=1/2$ so there exists $x_n\in (0,1)$ with $f_n(x_n)=1/4.$

But $f(x_n)=0$ so $$\|f-f_n\|\ge |f(x_n)-f_n(x_n)|=|0-1/4|=1/4.$$ So $(\|f-f_n\|)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ does not converge to $0.$

Your reasoning, that if the convergence were uniform then $f$ would be continuous, is correct. However, in some cases, such as in this problem, we can bypass that.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely correct. All $f_n$ are continuous, and the limiting function is not. Hence the convergence cannot be uniform. It is uniform on $[a,b]$ for $0<a<b<1$ though.

Comment: The O.P. is mistaken about $f(0).$ For all $n$ we have $f_n(0)=0,$ so $f(0)=0.$

Comment: Oh, yeah. That makes sense